# Apple Style Gallery - Image Parallax Easing

Tags: css, css-animations, parallax

I am hoping to re-create a gallery just like the one of the iPhone 6s Image Gallery demo. I like how they have created each image a different size tile and that as you scroll, the image very slowly scrolls with it.

[LINK HERE](http://www.apple.com/uk/iphone-6s/cameras/photos/)

I have created a similar image gallery like the example, but I am not sure how to:

1) Re-create the parallax easing on the images as it scrolls

2) Have all images fade-in on load

Could someone help?

[FIDDLE HERE](http://www.bootply.com/FR4KL20CrE)

Answer (score 2):

There is couple ways to do this.

You could use parallax effects,transform/translateY or

```
$('#outer').bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
if (!(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta == 120))
```

The full function is in the link.

Now for fading in the picture on load(You can do on scroll as well), it depends if you want and can use jQuery, as it's the simplest.

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('img').not(':visible').fadeIn(1000);
});

function makeVisible() {
$('img').load(function () {
    $(this).fadeIn(1000);
});
});

makeVisible();
```

This is just a general direction, there are more than one way to do this, I have listed what would be the simplest way to me.